# My register button does not work properly in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created project regarding user registering and logging connected with database and unfortunately the register button doesn't work properly whenever I tried to press register in order to check my inputs correct or toasted a message to fill the blanks... here is my cod

Register Java class:

```
package com.example.registration;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edtUsernameRegister, edtPasswordRegister , edtEmail;
    Button btnRegister;

    User user;
    Helper helper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_MODE_CHANGED);

        edtUsernameRegister = findViewById(R.id.inputUsername);
        edtPasswordRegister = findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
        edtEmail = findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
        btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

        helper = new Helper(this);
        user = new User();


        TextView btn=findViewById(R.id.alreadyHaveAccount);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btnRegister) {
            String username = edtUsernameRegister.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
            String password = edtPasswordRegister.getText().toString().trim();
            String email = edtEmail.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!username.isEmpty() || !password.isEmpty() || !email.isEmpty()) {
                user.setUsername(username);
                user.setemail(email);
                user.setPassword(password);
                user.setType("customer");
                boolean didSucceed = helper.registerUser(user);

                if (didSucceed) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent iii = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(iii);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Registration failed..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "insert all fields, please..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Register.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/bb">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputUsername"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_bg"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputEmail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_bg"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/inputUsername"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/inputUsername"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputUsername" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputPassword"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_bg"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_security"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="******"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/inputEmail"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/inputEmail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputEmail" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
        android:text="Register"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/inputPassword"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/inputPassword"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputPassword" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alreadyHaveAccount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:shadowColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:text="Already Have an Account?"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnRegister"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnRegister"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnRegister" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

User class:

```
package com.example.registration;

public class User {
    private  int u_id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String type;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getemail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setemail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getu_id() {
        return u_id;
    }
}
```

Helper Class:

```
package com.example.registration;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "onlySoccer" ;
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 7;

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "create table user(" +
            "u_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, " +
            "username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, password TEXT NOT NULL, type text, email text NOT NULL UNIQUE);" ;

        private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MATCHSSCORE = "create table matchsScore(" +
            "m_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, " +
            "f_name text unique, t_score Ingteger , f_image text, s_name text, s_image text);";

    public Helper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MATCHSSCORE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user" );
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean registerUser(User user) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("username", user.getUsername());
        values.put("email", user.getemail());
        values.put("password", user.getPassword());
        values.put("type", user.getType());
        boolean isValid = getWritableDatabase().insert("user", null, values) > 0;
        return isValid;
    }

    public int getUserId(User user){
        Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase()
                .rawQuery("select _id from user where username=?",
                        new String[]{user.getUsername()});

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    }

    public boolean userIsRegistered(User user) {
        String table_name = "user";
        String[] columns = {"u_id"};
        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();

        String selection = "username" + " = ?" + " and" + " password" + " = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()};

        Cursor cursor = database.query(table_name,
                columns,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                null);

        return cursor.getCount()>0;
    }

    public void insertMatchsScore(MatchsScore matchsScore){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("f_name", matchsScore.getF_name());
        values.put("s_name", matchsScore.getS_name());
        values.put("f_image", matchsScore.getF_image());
        values.put("s_image", matchsScore.getS_image());
        values.put("t_score", matchsScore.getT_score());

        getWritableDatabase().insert("matchScore", null, values);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if (v == btnRegister)
```

try a switch case statement like so

```
switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnRegister:
         
        String username = edtUsernameRegister.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String password = edtPasswordRegister.getText().toString().trim();
        String email = edtEmail.getText().toString().trim();

        if (!username.isEmpty() || !password.isEmpty() || !email.isEmpty()) {
            user.setUsername(username);
            user.setemail(email);
            user.setPassword(password);
            user.setType("customer");
            boolean didSucceed = helper.registerUser(user);

            if (didSucceed) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent iii = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(iii);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Registration failed..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "insert all fields, please..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: It's working now ,, however. it doesn't validate the inputs whether the user inputs the all fields or not .. it's switched to login activity directly without validation

Comment: Also it craches

Comment: @AHumaidi9 if its opening the activity directly its probably because of that onClick method added directly to the button at the top. But you can make a different question for that and refer me to it I will help for now if my code helped you solve this question it will be nice if you accept the answer